# Dual Circuit Health

Tags: redundancy, failover

I would like to know best practices for failing over onto a secondary MPLS or Internet circuit. I understand the concepts behind BGP and influencing in and outbound routes, however what I am looking for are ways to "track" a circuit failure so that I truly know it is down, before I failover. Or is it best to leave the primary down until it can be verified of its health?

Today I could have a "switching/bounding" effect, if the primary circuit is flapping.

I know this topic is very broad and covers a number of situations, but what are most companies doing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I failover', it wouldn't be manual process rather triggered by linkstate or bfd/igp/bgp liveness timers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'll want to be using BFD to ensure your forwarding plane is working. If not, you can run IP SLA, to at least two external IPs and fail over if you can't get to both

Comment: I like the idea about monitoring two IP's. Today I only do one. With this solution it still only monitors ICMP connectivity. Is it possible to configure an IPSLA with a regex value to query a website, or something more sohisticated?

Comment: Yes, you can do HTTP GET in IP SLA. If you go this route, have duplicate set of static routes to avoid blackholing. That is metric/admin_distance N which is not tracked and another with metric/admin_distance <N  which is tracked. This way if all tracking fails and all tracked routes are pulled, you'll fallback to using non-tracked routes, as we presume network is ok, IP SLA measurement not.

Comment: To give you a little more insight. I have two internet circuits that use the same BGP AS, I leverage prepending on the secondardy circuit. These circuits are at two different physical locations.

Comment: To give you a little more insight. I have two internet circuits that use the same BGP AS, I leverage prepending on the secondary circuit for inbound routes, and outbound routes are leveraged by EIGRP. These circuits are at two different physical locations, but connect on the back end through a L2 connection. I like the idea of using two SLA monitors. Are the SLA monitors "and" or "or" based? Meaning, if the ping SLA is still up, but the HTTP GET SLA fails it pulls the route? Is it possible to track a BGP object, like pulling the network statement?  Do you have config examples?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're doing, if you're manually 'failing over'. It should happen automatically either when you experience change in linkstate or BFD/IGP/BGP liveness timers expire.

To avoid routing protocol instability caused by rapid flapping you can use 'dampening' in IOS config or 'hold-time' in JunOS config, both will allow you to create artificial delay on interface going 'up', so rapidly flapping interface would not be seen up at all.

IOS config is much better, as it's exponential back-off (the more you flap, the longer you delay), JunOS config is static delay.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more detail on how to configure "dampening" and give a situation on when it would be appreciate?

Comment: You mentioned worry about 'switching' on a circuit which is 'flapping'. If your primary circuit is rapidly going up/down, you'd normally try to converge to use the primary circuit as fast as possible, causing packet loss as traffic keeps on attempting to enter the flapping circuit. With dampening the flapping interface would never be considered to be up from routing-protocol point-of-view, so traffic would be kept at backup circuit until primary stabilizes.

Comment: I think this may work from an MPLS perspective when I have two circuits terminating into a single location. Is it possible to "dampen" from a CE router? What event determines the circuit is "stabilized". Also, do you have any config examples you could share?

Comment: If you'd mention your vendor, it would help with example. But it's literally 'dampening' on IOS (with optional parameters) and it's literally 'hold-time up <milliseconds>' to wait milliseconds until becoming up. For optional parameters to IOS exponential backoff you can read http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/s_ipevdp.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are strictly talking about circuit failover, on Cisco devices you can use ip sla to track an object and modify your routing table based on the availability of said object.

Other vendors have their own capabilities - Palo Alto has object tracking built in to their policy based routing engine. Those are the vendors I'm most familiar with, I'd be surprised if you couldn't do similar things with Juniper and others.